# jquery .css("border-color") does not return anything

Tags: jquery, css, border

I wrote the following jquery javascript stuff

```
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    var element = event.target;
    $(element).css("border","black solid 1px");
});

$(document).mouseout(function(event) {
    var element = event.target;
    console.log( "1 = "$(element).css("border-color") )
    $(element).css("border","0px");
    console.log( "2 = " + $(element).css("border-color") )
});
```

It basicly draws a frame around a hovered element. When running this in chrome the output of `console.log( "1 = "$(element).css("border-color") )` is "" i.e. nothing. The same is true for `console.log( "2 = "$(element).css("border-color") )`. But I'd expect black. I also tried `borderColor` which does not work either.

Anyway when hovering an element a frame is drawn around this element as I would expect. Why then does the output give nothing in return?

Comment: This may be unrelated but you have a syntax error. It should be `console.log( "1 = " + $(element).css("border-color");`. Don't forget those semicolons either!

Answer (score 21):

You cannot use shorthand for jquery. You have to be more specific, e.g. "border-top-color"

Let me know if that works.

Comment: this will not work, you need to specify property name as CamelCase

Comment: @semyon: jQuery will translate `border-top-color` to `borderTopColor`. So, either works..

Comment: @semyon I was just keeping the solution in line with his question. Jquery plays nice with either.

Comment: To let you know that it worked, as requested: Worked perfectly while fixing the issue for IE11. Chrome seems to be supporting BorderColor, while IE11 required the borderTopColor.

Comment: completely ridiculous...if you can set it via "borderColor," why won't jQuery let you retrieve it via "borderColor" in IE?  Can't we all as devs just agree to not support IE due to inconsistent and time wasting lack of cross browser functionality?? smh...thx guys!

Comment: I know this is old so maybe it has already been fixed but interestingly enough, jQuery returned the `background` property in Chrome but not in IE. I had to use `background-color` to get the color in both IE and Chrome. Very weird.

Comment: I had an issue with Firefox. In Chromium 53 `$(element).css("border-color");` worked fine, but not in Firefox 50. Had to use `$(element).css("border-top-color");`

Answer (score 11):

Use **jQuery(...).css(“borderTopColor”)**

**This works**: http://jsfiddle.net/JvTwp/

Answer (score 9):

```
$("#mytext").focus(function () {

  $(this).css({'background-color': '#FFFFCC'});

  $(this).css("border", "black solid 1px"); 

}).blur(function () {

  $(this).css({'background-color': '#fff'});
  $(this).css("border", "#DCDCDC solid 1px");

 });


<input type="text" id="mytext">
```

**Try this**

http://jsfiddle.net/prabirchoudhury/kcnT8/

Answer (score 3):

With the help of an inspector you can verify that doesn't exists a property named 'border-color', you are looking for 'border-[top|bottom|left|right]-color'

Comment: yes, and do not forget to use CamelCased name, not hyphenated one

Answer (score 0):

As long as you set the color with JavaScript/jQuery (as in I don't think it'll work if it was only set in CSS).  I haven't figured out how to access these properties via jQuery, but you can still access the border properties using native JavaScript.

```
console.log(this.style.borderTop); // should return '1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0)'
console.log(this.style.borderColor); // should return 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
```

Note:
`.border`(`Top`|`Right`|`Bottom`|`Left`) seems pretty reliable, but
`.border`(`Style`|`Color`|`Width`) yields mixed results.

I think it depends if the shorthand sides are identical; e.g:

- All sides the identicle
- top and bottom (with each other) / left and right (with each other)
- top / left and right (with each other) / bottom
- All four being set differently doesn't appear to work
- I've yet to have success with just `element.style.border` whole border set at once (i.e. `element.style.border = '1px solid #000'`)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you do not have a border to begin with, according to the snippet of code you posted, you are only creating the border with jQuery... according to events. A better way would be to define a border for the element within your .css file and then use jQuery to change the border as needed...

if you do not wish to define a border for the element in your .css file see the below snippet:

note that .css("border-color") is not valid, use camel-Case instead. For example:

```
$("element").css("borderColor", "1px solid black");
```